# flask-sqlalchemy: import models going wrong

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am building an app with Flask and Sqlalchemy.
My `app.py` file starts like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
from models import User
```

and my `models.py` goes like this:

```
from app import db
class User
....
```

so when I run `python app.py`, I get an error saying "cannot import name User". I guess there's a circular import somewhere, I don't understand how to fix it.

But if I create another file `run.py` with just

```
from app import app
app.run()
```

Everything works perfectly. But why does this break circular import? I can't understand this.

Comment: Are there any other imports used in those files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got it right: this is a circular import problem.

The way that I've gotten around this is by having another file, a `shared.py` file in the root directory. In that file, create the database object,

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

In your `app/init.py`, don't create a new db object. Instead, do

```
from shared import db
db.init_app(app)
```

In any place that you want to use the db object, including your models file, import it from `shared.py`:

```
from shared import db
# do stuff with db
```

This way, the object in the shared file will have been initialized with the app context, and there's no chance of circular imports.