# flask failed to import module on a server context

Tags: python, flask

I encounter a weird import error when I try to deploy an app built on flask, sqlalchemy on a server. The app works well when I run it on my localhost. However, it raises an import error when I run the app on a server. I suspect the cause of my problem is a circular import. But it's really weird that it works on a local environment but fails on a server environment.

I have file structure looks like the following:

```
.
├── __main__.py
├── instance
│   ├── config.cfg
├── theapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── views.py
```

**init**.py

```
# File for initializing the application and set up global variables(app, db)


...
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
CONFIG_FILE = os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'config.cfg')

# Instantiate the application and initializes the login manager.
def create_app(app, config):
    app.config.update(SECRET_KEY=config['key']['SECRET_KEY'], SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=config['app']['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'],
                      DEBUG=config['app']['DEBUG'])

# Read configuration
config = ConfigParser()
config.read(CONFIG_FILE)
create_app(app, config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# These imports are useful. They help to avoid cyclic import
from lemur import views, models
```

views.py

```
from theapp import (app, db)
...
```

models.py

```
from theapp import db
...
```

**main**.py

```
from theapp import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The error is(in views.py):

```
cannot import name models
```

I have tried a method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691616/flask-sqlalchemy-import-models-going-wrong) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your $PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @rfkortekaas when I ` echo $PYTHONPATH `, I get nothing.